# Google Spreadsheet, Substitute Integer with String

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hey there and thanks in advance.

I'm exporting the API of an application onto my spreadsheet, which works fine. Due to how the API was programmed however, some of the columns now contain the `TypeID` (an integer representing the "name") and not the actual name. I know what `TypeID` represents what `Name`, so what I'm looking for is a way to substitute all entries of said column with the actual name.

I have already begun to make a humongus switch case in the script editor that just checks every cell in that column and based of the contents substitues the right name, but as you can probably imagine that would take a while.

Just wondering if there is a "cleaner" and more effective way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend making a JSON object to represent your switch case and call that

i.e :

```
var jsonMap = {"TYPEID":"NAME"};
```

Then call :

```
 jsonMap[fieldValue]
```

To return the correct value for that field

You could have the script trigger on row modification and have it translate that way.

Alternatively I'd recommend mapping the field before it is exported into sheets using the language you're exporting in and have the data enter the sheet correctly